# bot won't delete message after let it go for 5 sec

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a problem : my bot won't delete the message after letting it go for 5 sec.

Here is my code :

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(",")) {
    message.delete(); // You can put it here.
  }
});
```

The error :

```
    log (node:492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at Message.delete (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:577:60)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/index.js:40:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/Boorubot-2/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
(node:492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
```

Comment: The [`<Message>#delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) method is a function which does not accept any options, it is associated to a `Message` object and returns a promise to delete the message, your error seemingly isn't with deleting it rather something else... What's your `index.js` line 40?

Comment: In addition to what @Zero said, the event `message` is deprecate and has been replaced in V13 by `messageCreate`. I guess by your error, that you are using V13, so I'd suggest changing that